# What is the alternative for ADODB to open the connection of database of .DB file

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I don't want to use the ADODB for connection of database, because it is requires the .net framework 4.5. So i want to run my app in win xp so Windows xp dose not supports .net 4.5 what should I use of instead of.

Thanks.

Comment: .net 4.5 is not supported on xp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989893/net-framework-4-5-operating-system-requirements-no-vista-and-xp

Comment: What type of database is the .db file?

Answer (score 1):

ADODB is now considered outdated (although you *could* still use it a VB.NET project you should avoid it) - consider instead using ADO.NET.

The Highest .NET Framework you can install on Windows XP is 4.0 so you can use this to connect your your db file.

You don't mention the specific database type you are using but there are tons of examples for this sort of thing. Search for "getting started VB.NET ADO.NET [insert your database type here]"

Answer (score 0):

You could use Microsoft ADO.NET which is supported by earlier versions of .NET framework.

```
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx.aspx
```